# Smallest positive number in a vector recursively

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm writing a function that is supposed to recursively find the smallest positive number in a give vector of ints.

Right now my code looks like this:

```
 #include <vector>
 using namespace std;
 int rec_min_pos(const vector<int> & nums, int size) {
    if (size < 1) {
    return -1;
    } else {
        int min = rec_min_pos(nums, size - 1);
        if(min < 0){
            if(nums[size - 1] <= 0){
                return -1;
            }else{
                return nums[size-1];
            }
        }else {
            if (min < nums[size - 1]) {
                return min;
            } else {
                return nums[size - 1];
            }
        }
    }
}
int main(){
    vector<int> nums = {2, -3, 6, -21, 10, -80, 8};
    cout << rec_min_post(nums, nums.size());
}
```

If I run this, I get `8`, which  is presumably because the next element is negative.

The previous version:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int rec_min_pos(const vector<int> & nums, int size) {
    if (size < 1) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        int min = rec_min_pos(nums, size - 1);

        if (min < nums[size - 1]) {
            return min;
        } else {
            return nums[size - 1];
        }
    }
}
int main(){
    vector<int> nums = {2, -3, 6, -21, 10, -80, 8};
    cout << rec_min_post(nums, nums.size());
}
```

I would get `-80` which is in fact the smallest value, but I need the smallest positive value.

What can I do to get the smallest positive value from the integer vector?

Comment: In the 'else' part in your first version, you don't check if the numbers are positive.

Comment: I think "recursive" is a strange requirement. Your algorithm meets that requirements and is essentially correct, but it would be more efficient to split the vector into equal pieces and recurse - then the call stack would only be log(n) deep, and not n, which can cause a stack overflow.

Comment: @ArndtJonasson it absolutely is a strange requirement. However, it is a requirement and so I must try to find a solution.

Comment: @ArndtJonasson: tail recursion will completely eliminate the stack issue.

Comment: @YvesDaoust It will if the language handles it and you write the code that way, that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def SPN(nums, s):
  if s == 0:
    # Empty array
    return +∞
  if nums[s-1] > 0:
    # num[s] is admissible, recurse and keep the smallest
    return min(nums[s-1], SPN(nums, s-1))
  else:
    # Just recurse
    return SPN(nums, s-1)

print SPN(nums, len(nums)
```

The c++ version:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int rec_min_pos(const vector<int> & nums, int size) {
    if (size < 1) {
        return INT_MAX;
    }
    if(nums[size-1] > 0){
        return min(nums[size-1], rec_min_pos(nums, size-1));
    }
    else{
        return rec_min_pos(nums, size-1);
    }
}
```

---

**Update:**

Assuming that reserving `INT_MAX` is not allowed to represent +∞, we can use a negative instead, say `-1`, with the convention that `min(x,-1) = x`.

```
Infty= -1 # Conventional +∞

def Min(a, b):
  if b == Infty:
    return a
  else:
    return min(a, b)

def SPN(nums, s):
  if s == 0:
    # Empty array
    return Infty 
  if nums[s-1] > 0:
    # num[s] is admissible, recurse and keep the smallest
    return Min(nums[s-1], SPN(nums, s-1))
  else:
    # Just recurse
    return SPN(nums, s-1)
```

That leads us to a more elegant version if we use the convention that any negative value represents +∞:

```
def Min(a, b):
  if a < 0:
    return b
  if b < 0:
    return a
  return min(a, b)

def SPN(nums, s):
  if s == 1:
    return nums[0] # Assumes len(nums) > 0

  return Min(nums[s-1], SPN(nums, s-1))
```

Elegant version in C++:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int minimum(int a, int b){
    if(a < 0){
        return b;
    }
    if(b < 0){
        return a;
    }
    return min(a, b);
}
int SPN(vector<int> nums, int size){
    if(size == 1){
        return nums[0];
    }
    return minimum(nums[size-1], SPN(nums, size-1));
}
```

Comment: You should have said so - it looks very much like Python.

Comment: when I run this, I get -1 (I replaced `+∞` with `-1`) so it doesn't work with the given input

Comment: @FMashiro: as far as I know, +∞ is deemed to be positive.

Comment: @YvesDaoust could be, but apart from that, it shouldn't get to that case it should find `2`.

Comment: @FMashiro: it does !

Comment: @ArndtJonasson: come on, from the very first token you see that it is not c++. But the translation to c++ is so trivial !

Comment: This is the danger with answering in pseudocode you haven't run. Now we are debugging your answer instead. I also do not get 2.

Comment: @ArndtJonasson: I did run the pseudocode and it does return 2. Double check your own work. Read all comments.

Comment: But how do you "run" pseudocode? I see it is correct if the infinity value in fact exist, so -1 is not correct, and your pseudocode is correct as intended.

Comment: You can run pseudocode by hand if you wish. Also note that it is a very common convention to set the minimum of an empty list to be a conventional +∞.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I've gotten your pseudocode to run, however, c++ doesn't know infinity, and `INT_MAX` is a perfectly valid value, so this answer still does not work.

Comment: @FMashiro: sorry, it does. You can show your code if you want.

Comment: Side note: if you do want to use Python, you can use float('+Inf') for infinity. I'm not sure if it's good programming practice, but it should be well-defined here.

Comment: @ArndtJonasson: I said conventional +∞. You can think of different ways to implement, depending on taste or coding constraints.

Comment: @FMashiro: the output of the C++ code is indeed 2, I don't see why you claim it doesn't work.

Comment: @YvesDaoust My bad, I tried to alter it to fit the other requirement which is to return `-1` when no positive integers are found. However I now see how your function approaches this. I'll mark it as correct since I didn't mention the `-1` requirement,

Comment: @YvesDaoust thanks for the trouble you went through! Added a final compilable c++ version as an edit.

Comment: @FMashiro: need to check if 0 is considered positive or not.

Comment: @YvesDaoust 0 is considered positive.

Comment: @FMashiro: it is a matter of convention. Usually, it is not.

Comment: @YvesDaoust in this particular case, it would be considered positive.