# c++ function return the smallest positive integer in a vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

I am using this code below which returns the smallest positive integer in a vector. I got the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49360036/smallest-positive-number-in-a-vector-recursively?rq=1). My question is there a reason to pass the size to the function, can you not calculate it in the function body?

Also what is the second `if()` testing for? I can't understand how this if statement works?

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int rec_min_pos(const vector<int> & nums, int size) {
    if (size < 1) {
        return INT_MAX;
    }
    if(nums[size-1] > 0){
        return min(nums[size-1], rec_min_pos(nums, size-1));
    }
    else{
        return rec_min_pos(nums, size-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you need the `size` argument, because the size of the vector doesn't change. And how would you calculate the size in the function body anyway?

Comment: @MichaelWalz could you not call `nums.size()` ?

Comment: The `size` argument should be named `index` or something. It's pretty confusing, because it hasn't got anything to do with the vector's size.

Comment: Vectors know how big they are. But note that the function is recursive, it doesn't operate on the entire vector each time.

Comment: The `size` argument maybe could be named `last_elem`, it's necessary because the function works recursively instead of with a loop. It's not really the size of the vector, but the portion of the vector where the function will search for the minimum positive element (the first call should be with the full size and recursive calls look into smaller portions). The second if checks if the last element is not negative, otherwise it returns the best value found in the next portion of the vector.

Comment: What happened when you ignored the `size` argument and used `nums.size()` instead? What did you learn from this? Oh yeah, and what did you see when you stepped through the program in a debugger?

Comment: As an aside, writing recursive functions like this isn't very sensible. Prefer something involving `std::min_element` and a suitable predicate. (e.g. `[](int lhs, int rhs){ return std::tie(!std::signbit(lhs), lhs) < std::tie(!std::signbit(rhs), rhs) }`.

Comment: @Caleth the suggestion in your comment is probably beyond the scope of the OP for the moment. But of course you're right. BTW I rolled back your edit of my answer, forward declaration is not needed here.

Comment: @Caleth could you expand on your answer please if you have got time? Have you posted a lamda function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second `if` statement checks for positivity of the element, since the function shall return the minimum *positive* integer.

Your function is recursive and the '`size`' argument is actually one plus the index to the last element to be tested. This allows a simple recursive function design, but requires an additional argument. It's presumably better to make these points explicit in the function interface

```
inline int recursive_min_positive(const int*arr, size_t i)
{
    return 
        i==0? std::numeric_limits<int>::max() :
        arr[i-1]<=0? recursive_min_positive(arr,i-1) :
        std::min(arr[i-1],recursive_min_positive(arr,i-1) ;
}

int min_positive(std::vector<int> const&arr)
{
    return recursive_min_positive(arr.data(), arr.size());
}
```

Recursive function design is often elegant, but inefficient (though compilers tend to unroll the recursion). Here, a non-recursive implementation is actually shorter and clearer.

```
int min_positive(std::vector<int> const&arr)
{
    int result = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    for(auto val : arr)
        if(0 < val  &&  val < result) result = val;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all comments: you can overload the function like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

// Original function with size argument
int rec_min_pos(const vector<int> & nums, int size) {
  if (size < 1) {
    return INT_MAX;
  }
  if (nums[size - 1] > 0) {
    return min(nums[size - 1], rec_min_pos(nums, size - 1));
  }
  else {
    return rec_min_pos(nums, size - 1);
  }
}

// Overloaded rec_min_pos function
int rec_min_pos(const vector<int> & nums) {
    // here we just call the original rec_mon_pos function
    return rec_min_pos(nums, nums.size());
}

int main()
{
  vector<int> v{ 9,2,7,3,7,5,6 };
  cout << rec_min_pos(v);  // call the overloaded function
}
```

Output:

```
2
```

Comment: thank you for you're suggestion, this doesn't compile you're passing 2 arguments `return rec_min_pos(nums, nums.size());`?

Comment: @arcoxiatom I changed the code snipped into a full compileable sample.

Answer (score 0):

Not related to the recursive function, but expanding on my comment:

```
int min_positive(std::vector<int> & nums)
{
    auto elem = std::min_element(nums.begin(), nums.end(), 
        [](int lhs, int rhs){ return std::tie(std::signbit(lhs), lhs) < std::tie(std::signbit(rhs), rhs); }
    );
    if ((elem == nums.end()) || std::signbit(*elems)) { return MAX_INT; }
    return *elem;
}
```

Here we define a comparison function that orders positive before negative, and then by value. We use the three argument `std::min_element`, which will find us an iterator in `nums`.

The first check handles an empty `nums`, and the second one where every value is negative, both of which the original ignores, returning `MAX_INT`